# python floating point nature and converting to a smaller type

Tags: python, floating-point

I am trying to understand the exact nature of `float` when it comes to python. Apparently, python stores floats in a `PyFloatObject` type which contains a `double`. However, how can I force it to behave like a 32 bit floating point variable ? Is there another type for this ?

Comment: @Sven : student question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The built-in `float` type of Python always uses double precision (unless you compile a custom version of the interpreter).  You can use the [`array`](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html) module to get 32-bit floats:

```
a = array.array("f")
```

will define an array of 32-bit floats.

The external NumPy package also provides a scalar 32-bit floating-point type, namely `numpy.float32`.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a built-in type in Python that's represented using 32-bit floats.

However, see Sven Marnach's answer for alternatives.